# How to generically type a modified dictionary of inconsistent functions

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that needs to convert a dictionary of functions with partially dynamic properties into a new dictionary of functions with similar properties.

What I have so far:

```js
interface Dictionary<T extends any> {
    [key: string]: T
}

type InputFunction<T> = (value: T, parameters?: any) => T

type InputFunctionMap<T> = Dictionary<InputFunction<T>>

type OutputFunction = (parameters?: any) => void

type OutputFunctionMap<T, U extends InputFunctionMap<T>> = {
    [P in keyof U]: OutputFunction
}

function create<T>(key: string, value: T): [() => T, (value: T) => void]
function create<T, U = InputFunctionMap<T>>(key: string, value: T, inputs: U): [() => T, Readonly<OutputFunctionMap<T, U>>]
function create<T, U = InputFunctionMap<T>>(key: string, value: T, inputs?: U): [() => T, (value: T) => void] | [() => T, Readonly<OutputFunctionMap<T, U>>] {
    // ...
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
const [getFoo, updateFoo] = create('foo', 'FOO')

getFoo() // => 'FOO'

updateFoo('foo') // => 'foo'

getFoo() // => 'foo'

interface MathParameters {
    operation: 'MULTIPLY' | 'DIVIDE'
    operand: number
}

const [getBar, {addToBar, addSevenToBar, applyMathToBar}] = create('bar', 0, {
    addToBar: (value, parameters: number) => value + parameters,
    addSevenToBar: (value) => value + 7,
    applyMathToBar: (value, parameters: MathParameters) => {
        switch (parameters.operation) {
            case 'MULTIPLY':
                return value * parameters.operand

            default:
                return value
        }
    }
})

getBar() // => 0

addSevenToBar()

getBar() // => 7

addToBar(3)

getBar() // => 10

applyMathToBar({operation: 'MULTIPLY', operand: 2})

getBar() // => 20
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to properly and generically type `parameters` (I don't want them to be `any`) so that the type can be inferred from the input function and be correctly available as the parameter in the output function.

**Update:**

Thank you for the support so far!

I'm just having trouble getting the ouput mapping to work as intended: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYDECuA7AxgHhgPigF5YoIAPYCDAEwGcoAKOAJwHMAuKODEAGigA6YazZ0uCDADMILKAEEAlMUIA3APYIaAWABQUA1AD8TYYNHiFyoms079hrhgirZevaEixESAAqs4AFs6PEISGDJKanomUS4efiERdktJGTklFSgNLT1DYwU8xyhnVxZ3XSlMLGAEdQwoLBYIOCpQxiKDAGsIEC46YBZJNj5O7LgkNAguGFHdRS4AbUZrQlmmVQmpmdXsuwBdPSrsWvrG5taIHDHZsYBVSKpaBgAlCCx1FhocHpB1KSgdwEjE2k2msAEZgs8V4uxyNHwenwHQc3V6-UGwzm+VB2whY0kYDQwEsQL0Cygy126zecBo9SQIBwAG9KQBpKCSKC-f6A-YzHzobA4O6LNn7QgAX3wh0q1VODSaLTaN2xhgeFCeMTeHy+P16vKBGy24PWUJSMJAcLsiN0yLGvwxQwwIzGuNNaoMhOJdCMXDJ8w4YwAPpSVll1iCTTssvDZflQ1SIwJafSMIyWezOQ0eQC7vzvMghbhReKpTKoMyCQDGN6ScQiCRMDQIFJJBAaMoq6j8lBmsA0CwGosxr3DOGbOMwZ6x+PQTHJ93Z8uoAB6Vej2eSmf5eOGSUVfL9wfDzcGCdqE07wwAeQARgArd7AQRSZoQABeEBRK9vj+fgi-HQtYYESJKKIIzQ0GgWDfmeK4-r+K7qMSYF0NeSGGBgQQQBhK67EumGzh8GADNmYHEORPqLNhgTQHADC5nyh5EWOKHAGhNE4dwjEGnm+yUYw5piAKyD+CwQQhJ4EC8nW+AEfBrEGOuilIQeuiqb+x5DlA7FoZpvbbgZ+TMpKPGVlmXJMfmomoNUIpihKUBGT2y6KHh7ljLK6l6CRZGLGwEDAAAQqwAisnSNAwOooUsAIkUAMouNQ0Wxc5AkkEqlyMAA5HerA5QIAAM4VjIlyUYKlrBcFGYJwiaUAANRQAA7DOkVVSwNXugIYABHRVAsJYGBoIEd6yPVYJNVAfUSQNsjoXokqKBUgUhawKyCMA6i+M0WAIHQdQYCsFTla4lUxRtK26B1l0sIwAAc11AA)

```js
type TailParams<T> = T extends (arg: any, ...args: infer A) => void
    ? A
    : never

const input = inputs[name as keyof U]

outputs[name as keyof U] = (...args: TailParams<typeof input>) => {
    //
}
```

Throws: `Type '(...args: TailParams<U[keyof U]>) => void' is not assignable to type 'TailFunc<U[keyof U]>'.`

Comment: The functions you pass to `create` don't have any types assigned to their parameters so they will be `any` in the output functions

Comment: Even if I add types in the input functions parameters, the `InputFunction` and `OutputFunction` types can't have `parameters` defined as `any`. This `any` blocks any sort of inference possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably type `create()` like this:

```
type TailFunc<T> = T extends (h: any, ...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : never;

declare function create<T>(key: string, value: T): [() => T, (value: T) => void]
declare function create<T, U extends Record<keyof U, (value: T, ...args: any) => any>>(
    key: string,
    value: T,
    inputs: U
): [() => T, { [K in keyof U]: TailFunc<U[K]> }]
```

The `TailFunc<T>` type takes a function type `T` and returns a new function where the first parameter has been removed.  So `TailFunc<(a: string, b: number, c: boolean) => string>` becomes `(b: number, c: boolean) => string`.

The second call signature for `create()` is generic in `T` as usual, and `U`, which is the type of the `inputs` parameter.  This is constrained to `Record<keyof U, (value: T, ...args: any)=>any`, so it expects `U` to be an object type whose values are all functions whose first parameter is of type `T`.

The return type of that call signature is a tuple where the second element is the mapped type that performs `TailFunc` on all the properties of `U`.

Let's make sure it works:

```
getBar() 
addSevenToBar()
getBar() 
addToBar(3)
getBar() 
applyMathToBar({ operation: 'MULTIPLY', operand: 2 })
getBar()
```

Those all give no errors in the type system, so the types are what you want.  Whether or not it behaves as you expect at runtime depends on the implementation of `create()`, I guess.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYDECuA7AxgHhgPigF5YoIAPYCDAEwGcoAKACwC4o4MQAaKAOgFwATgHM67BBgBmEIVACCASmKFJMuQCUoAfiYC+wseyUqoW9hggA3WQG4AsACgnNCFiTDoUzFmAIA9hhQWEIQcFR4+IwA1hAg7HTAQpIivFZwSGgQ7DCK7ADajMpEhDC8jOmZ2bDFhFb+CDQAui5uHqFQ3th+gcGh4RB4vACqZJTU9GZu-kI0OLEg-lJQw+WVWTm8+obiHFy1eyD4UU5QZ1ALCUkp3Kfn69Vld2eSYGjAu8NOeVCFB2VQADevwA0lBJBc4ksVk0cohUD4cMN8iCmoQAL4tZzYpxYQKJX4iCDAFD+fy8NBgGgDUn+JrEPphKiMADkUjJLN4LJQAHkeSzFA5HESSWSik5KdSqLTWez-AKoE4RTLlE4nJIqEIpHAsNAALLhZgABWEcAAtsTZAxAc8oP5IEJwgEMOwWXrhgAZGAASSNHoAmiyoAAfKAsgAi3oAat7wwBRFm2+2yTg0CxoM0AI1kTnRasceIwBPyIoAQsJeMC4DQaDB-OWhLxqzQAMrWah1htNsBgJAgA3AZid4RQTEMkJMiCszPCTlQAAMldtzeHQnYFQyWV4YFNFs1uwwGezQgODygAGooDvHXurbdHOcODW2zYMKv1w9T5voJeAOz3x84B7PsByHethA-b9t13S0hF2UCTRvWC6AOG0H0fc46AAdwQYAsGYJhr3NZC+GTR0egwZQ0IwmjgjgOhoDdT0fT9QNWFtWiMNCYA0CEIIzwAKivGD91Ih1U3zTjH1cbU0CQYB2PQqSuOJXj+O-DjzjzJTR1zRR8zLYQikVRxmxfDtwKEcVhWJBtjKcFdLMYABmfSbOAOzVVM4D+0NVdGGBMinUCV13S9X0AznILaHYAAmUc3MMqyvKAA)

---

note that how to implement `create()` so that everything typechecks with the minimum of type assertions is outside the scope of the original question, so I'm only posting a link to one possible way to do it: [link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1&ssl=1&ssc=52&pln=3&pc=12#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYDECuA7AxgHhgPigF4oAKAOkrgCcBzAZwC5ZEkAFGuAW3r3wEpihAG4B7BABMAsAChZoSC2Qdq3XgWKwoEAB7AIGCfTI1azOBhAAaKJXKmmUBBgBmEalACCgoiPHSZKCCoAH4vWWCoZgwIYXdZWRdMLGAEUQwoLGoIOH0+UgjggGsIEGZ6YGpnWitCoOE4JDQIZhhamX5mAG1SH0I2sgamltg+qDFJAF1E5NT0zOzciBw62HbIgFVtPQMjKAAlCCxRagkcEpBRFygNm1Ih5tabOwdzSzGJiXxZfALA4tK5Uq1XWwQeIzaq2cYDQwEct1knSgPTGA0OcAk6SQIBwAG9kQBpJwZC5XG6TVqsdDYHAbLoEyaEAC++GmMiS2DmGSyOTyq0h-yCW10+kMxkOx1O51KZNug0ajzWtiodEcFhAH383xkv1WFyBVQwNVW4KeUIwMLhIWYCI6jFWAB9kb0hEr7gqIZqpo7naibOjMRhsXjCcSoKTrhsKUpUMlafTGVAWZMoLioddSNDYcYiLmoJgJBAXM4IBJBGnBZEoNlgGhqBkuqsq8EXb5xh7Qc3Iu6kK0xhWu4OoAB6YdNrtMztVtmRJkJSs1usN8dBVsiDsrqAAeQARgArI7AcgubIQABeED+Q5bu4PKXIF3omYt2cEcGMnmoqhxEZuAnI2QSGgWCXpug44ESIq7MYv4bLqlbXs2oiwpajj4l0bBhrB0bwMg1K4HSbCJpOYGIRg3AjASU6IVA-akdexwYBUxKWpoWZwl05FcBAbL0UOyHAKhnEUSmJAUCqDCUsonA8DgCgQGS7ECK6A40Yho58YOc5yAhalBIu9ZQAJqGacEJG6deuJMlA76pqGzjhjKkY4VScZ0gyzLUV2-BeUEPmrGy2myIxzFdLQEDAAAQjQNj4hiEgwKI0XUDY8UAMqxAYiXJUmokLLyl4AOQ7jQhU2AADLFqzpZlGDZTQzA9s0HwelAADUUAAOxTvF9XUI14I2GAMkRe4jgYGgXA7u4LXDO1UDDao3H6NQ9DtEy-DzuFUU0L05DAKIbDZFgCD0GkGC9PONVxHVSW7ZtMi9Xd1CkAAHA9QA)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but when testing your solution, I ran into an issue where the output functions aren't being typed as expected. See my update above, please.

Comment: My "link to code" link above shows that `addToBar` is typed `(parameters: number) => number` as you expect.  So I cannot reproduce your updated error.  Please try to produce a [mcve] that can demonstrate your issue in a standalone IDE without external dependencies.  [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) is an ideal place to test whether your issue is reproducible.  Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, very true. I'll have to look into this further.

Comment: One last issue, I've had to put the Playground link in the question due to it's length. Thank you very much

Comment: I've added a possible solution to that issue at the end of my answer.  In general it's not easy to get unresolved conditional types to type check inside function implementations; but that's a fundamentally different issue from this question, so I'm not going to get into it much here.  Good luck with your code!